# vba overflow error

Tags: excel, vba

I get an overflow error while trying to compile my userform:

Nr  Isikukood   Eesnimi Perenimi    Linn

1   38602110722 Priit   Burmeister  Jõgeva

```
Private Sub wisikukood_Change()
    Dim h As Range
    Set h = Range("tabel2")
    znimi.Value = h(wisikukood.Value, 3) + " " + h(wisikukood.Value, 4)
End Sub
```

The line is: `znimi.Value = h(wisikukood.Value, 3) + " " + h(wisikukood.Value, 4)`

I have `wisikukood` from listbox and 3 is for `firstname` from the table and 4 is for `lastname`.

znimi - textbox needed to be filled after choosing value from listbox wisikukood.

Comment: If you are trying to concatenate firstname and lastname use `&` instead of `+`

Comment: i tried to replace + into & nothing changed. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `wisikukood.value` - is it a numeric value? I presume it is the value selected from the listbox?

Comment: wisikukood.value is the personal ID - it is numeric yep - 11 digits and from listbox yes!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand your particular issue but assuming you want to use the 11 digit ID to get a name then it might be useful to use `VLOOKUP`:

```
Private Sub wisikukood_Change()
    Dim h As Range
    Set h = Range("tabel2")
    znimi.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookUp(wisikukood.Value, h, 3, false) & " " & WorksheetFunction.VLookUp(wisikukood.Value, h, 4, false)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello,what is for worksheetFunciton? must i replace it with something?

Comment: It gives me error: unable to get VLookup property of the worksheetfuncion class

Comment: @vovkjn - `WorksheetFunction` is a property used in VBA to call the `WorksheetFunction` object so that you can access functions used on a worksheet. To use `VLookUp` within VBA you need to use the syntax shown in the example and it should work if you copy and paste...

Comment: @vovkjn - can you update your initial post with what `Tabel2` looks like e.g. column headers, sample data etc.

Comment: @Remnant - i copied and pasted your code and it still gives me an error: unable to get the VLookup property of the worksheetfunction class

Comment: @Remnant - Nr Isikukood Eesnimi Perenimi Linn
           1 38602110722 Priit Burmeister Jõgeva

Comment: @vovkjn - to get `VLookUp` to work the 11 digit ID must be the first column in the table. Can you modify the table?

Comment: @vovkjn - not sure what else to suggest. If you could update your original post so I can see the table structure it may help...